# Drupal Commerce Payment Confirmation

Tags: commerce

I'm using the Drupal Commerce module (http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) along with the touchnet upay module (http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_touchnet_upay).  I've been able to set it up so when a user clicks checkout, they are redirected to the touchnet site and are successfully able to pay.  However, there's nothing on the Orders page that shows that the Order is complete, they still say Checkout:Payment under Order Status.  This is the status of the orders that have gone to the payment site but did not pay as well as the ones that actually paid.

Does anyone have experience with using Touchnet and Commerce and can tell me how I can get this to change to Payment:Complete or what Touchnet sends to my site and how I can capture that so I know that the order was actually paid for?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this became an automatic completion once the Touchnet account was setup correctly.  The three things that I found that need to happen to ensure it works successfully are:

1. Ensure that the postback site is www.example.com/touchnet (replace example.com with your website)
2. Ensure that the firewall is open on both your server and touchnet's server to allow traffic to each other
3. Ensure that the touchnet postback is using SSL

This made the completion of the payment become automatic without having to add a separate rule.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the Rules module and create a new rule.

Use react on: after payment is received/complete (or something along those lines)

Then use add action >> set a data value >> (find your order status field token)

Comment: I'm currently waiting on the touchnet guys to set up a test account so I can actually test payments without paying/bugging the person with the credit card every time heh.

I will let you know if this works as soon as that is set up and I can fully test it.  Thanks!

Comment: So I finally got the test server setup, and it's going through to touchnet, and when I get to the payment received page on touchnet, there's a link to take me back to my site.  However, I am always being redirected back to the review page with the Payment failed at the Payment server.  Any idea what could be causing this?